# Silence notifications but not calls

Tags: notifications, nexus-5, ringtone, silent-mode

During my night time, I would like to silence all app notifications, including text messages, emails and news alerts.

On the other hands, I do not want to silence calls. This is because calls after midnight are far less frequent than notifications, and they are probably intentional and urgent.

**Is there a way to silence every notification except a phone call?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can simply turn off/reduce your volume to 0 for the notifications and only keep the ringer volume as required.

You can do this under settings>sounds(As you have not specified any os details or the device make or model I can only give you a common answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a custom "Do Not Disturb" profile now, which allows calls by anyone or just from contacts.